# LuaLaTeX embed all fonts not working

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, embedding

I have the problem that my LuaLaTeX generated PDF apparently does not have all fonts that it uses embedded (the site where I let my document get printed says so).

So, I am using LuaLaTeX with the fontspec package, with these additional settings

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\setmonofont{Lucida Sans Typewriter}
```

Before, I accidentally had the input package in my document, so I removed it, but it did not help apparently.

This is my entire preamble, in case it is relevant:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\setmonofont{Lucida Sans Typewriter}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[]{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{pred}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}
\definecolor{pgrey}{rgb}{0.46,0.45,0.48}
\usepackage[]{calc}
\usepackage[]{fp}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{ltablex}
```

I have googled a lot now and I cant seem to find a solution for this, can anyone help?

Comment: Which font isnt being embedded?

Comment: LuaTeX does not support font mapping. use `Ligatures=TeX` instead of `Mapping=tex-text`.

Comment: make  an example _of the problem_ delete all the unrelated packages, add some text and show the output of `pdffonts` showing non-embedded fonts

Comment: I dont see the problem since only the site that will print my project says that not all fonts are included. When I check the fonts using windows, I clearly see that calibri for example, is embedded

Comment: The question is if  this is even relevant. The PDF looks fine, on my phone too. so im not sure what font would be relevant that is missing

Comment: you need to show an example if you want anyone to answer. what do you mean by "check the fonts using windows" which program did you use to check?

Comment: I used powershell, command findstr FontName, it list all embedded fonts.